# ogr SimplifyPreserveTopology does not keep the Topology

Tags: gdal, ogr, simplify

I use `ogr2ogr` to simplify a layer of polyline, from the document:

> -simplify tolerance: (starting with GDAL 1.9.0) distance tolerance for simplification. This method will preserve topology, in particular for
>   polygon geometries.

However, it seems that the topology are not kept.
http://pbrd.co/SPt39N

What's the problem?

And the gdal version I use is `1.10.0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current manual text at http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html is

> -simplify tolerance: (starting with GDAL 1.9.0) distance tolerance for simplification. Note: the algorithm used preserves topology per
>   feature, in particular for polygon geometries, but not for a whole
>   layer.

Topology preserving means in practice that parts of the multilinestring meet after simplification, polygons do not have self-intersections, inner rings in polygons stay inside outer rings, etc. Especially for polygon layers this method **does not** prevent gaps, overlaps, and slivers from appearing, even though this is the general belief. I would say that the method has a misleading name which makes users to believe that it saves the topology for the whole layer. However, the name and behaviour is the same in PostGIS and in JTS http://www.tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/simplify/TopologyPreservingSimplifier.html